# If i have a Array of parent Class A which contains child classes A and B is there any way i can call properties exclusive to A and B from the list

Tags: c#

I'm programming a card game right now, I have a deck of cards of type Card in an array.

All cards are either type Monster Card or Spell Card but when i put them in a list I don't know how to activate their methods from the list e.g. the monster card has the method attack where as the parent class and the other child Spell Card does not.

I cant do `Deck[5].Attack(int Target)`. How could i do this?

Comment: Can you provide some example code please?

Comment: No.. .and that's the point. If you have to cast you are usually doing it wrong.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the card classes. As i understand it you have class `A` and `B` and `B` derive from `A`. And you have `List<>` that contain both `A` and `B`.

Comment: Hard to say, but you could make a base Card class that both Monster and Spell derive from, then declare the Array of that base type.  The base type could have a `CanAttack` property that returns bool, and an `Attack()` method that can be overridden; Monster would override, while Spell would not.

Comment: One more idea - you can avoid inheritance entirely if your card classes "contain" Monster/Spells/Whatever then use use Card.Monster.Attack(something). This design pattern is called "Composition over inheritance".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If Deck[5] is a card that may be a Monster you can try to convert it to a Monster type before calling .Attack().

Instead of

`Deck[5].Attack(int Target)`,

```
Monster m = (Deck[5] as Monster);
if (m!=null) {
   m.Attack(Target)
}else{
   // not a monster
}
```

Comment: Note that, as mentioned in the comments above, this is almost always a sign of bad code.

Comment: @FreddieClarke It's a code smell when you see casting like this. It's often a sign that your initial design is flawed. In this case for example, it might be a bad idea to keep the monster cards and spell cards in the same collection. Do you really need to do that?

Comment: I liked the idea of them being in the same place but I've rearranged it now into 2 lists

Comment: @DavidG In most card games, the lists of cards (e.g. P1 draw/discard piles) are a mix of monster/spell/power cards. Using 2 lists would lose the ordering so you would create a new problem if you split them into new lists.

Comment: @FreddieClarke if you want to split your list by type you can also use something like this: List<Monster> Monsters = (List<Monster>)cards.OfType<Monster>().ToList()